# Cannot set property '3' of undefined in 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a 2 dimensional array but am getting this error.

I loop an object and try to assign them but it won't let me assign a value to the second dimension.

This is what I have:

```
//this is globally set
var gcollision = new Array();

function create() {
    for (var X in sdata) {
        X = parseInt(X);
        for (var Y in sdata[X]) {
            Y = parseInt(Y);
            width = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][2]);
            height = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][3]);
            for (i = X; i != X + width; i++) {
                //error occurs here "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined"
                gcollision[i][Y] = 1
                for (j = Y; j != Y + height; j++) {
                    gcollision[X][j] = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I make it set the value of properly?

EDIT  sdata looks like this:

```
var sdata = {"4":{"7":["1","7","3","3"]},"3":{"3":["2","8","1","1"]}};
```

Comment: what does your sdata look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//this is globally set
var gcollision = new Array();

function create(){
    for (var X in sdata) {
        X = parseInt(X);
        for (var Y in sdata[X]) {
            Y = parseInt(Y);
            width = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][2]);
            height = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][3]);

for (i=X; i!= X+width; i++) {
                 if( typeof gcollision[i] == 'undefined' ) gcollision[i] = new Array();
                 gcollision[i][Y] = 1

for (j=Y; j!=Y+height; j++) {
                 if( typeof gcollision[X] == 'undefined' ) gcollision[X] = new Array();
                 gcollision[X][j] = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically, even though you created your array, those indices do not exist yet, so you cannot reference them *as arrays* until after you define them as such.

If you set up your for loops a bit more optimally, you don't have to do isset and can just create the `gcol[index] = Array();` the right before the inner loop where it is first accessed.

Comment: One final question, is making an array for this better than having objects ? Which would be more efficient for doing checks later on ?

Comment: Also i do not understand what you mean about the setup of loops more optimally?

Comment: In Javascript, you wont notice much of a difference between the two (arrays and objects). Internally, they're probably handled the same way anyway. As for the optimizations, we're currently checking gcollision[]'s type in the internal loop because I don't know what type of data you have in the width & height variables; if you could restructure your function such that the gcol[index] arrays are created outside of that loop, you would save yourself an order of if-operations.

Comment: There is a slight issue, see screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/eSBzi.jpg , i also added sdata format to the question at the bottom. Is it deffinately listed as you would have expected, im not sure i can see how X:Y link together to do checks?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to initialize the first level of arrays, first.

```
function create() {
    for (var X in sdata) {
        X = parseInt(X);
        gcollision[X] = [];

        for (var Y in sdata[X]) {
            Y = parseInt(Y);
            width = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][2]);
            height = parseInt(sdata[X][Y][3]);
            for (i = X; i < X + width; i++) {
                gcollision[i][Y] = 1;

                for (j = Y; j < Y + height; j++) {
                    gcollision[X][j] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient way to do it ?

Comment: @Dave: Possibly. It shouldn't really matter that much, though.